# access jar in project from imported library - gradle / android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an android project (call it **myProj**) and android library (call it **myLib**)
Now inside the **myLib** I have a bunch of jar files that it rely on, and one of those jar that is inside **myLib** (libs folder) is needed for my android project **myProj**

How can I load / introduce that jar file to **myProj**??? no matter what I've done it can't see that jar - By that I mean that I can't add imports that are present inside that jar (and if I add it to **myProj** libs folder I get *Error: Program type already present:* (obviously)

I already tried creating third project with `configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('somelib.jar'))`https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415260/617373 but id didn't work at all...

and the following does not help either *File ->Project Structure ->App-> dependencies -> + ->add library* by adding a library you don't add its jars :(

Any Ideas are welcomed

Comment: I literally just asked this exact question lol https://stackoverflow.com/q/54817725/5184092

Comment: @luckyging3r you just got your self a +1... :)  that my exact problem! you might wanna try https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415260/617373 (didn't work for me...) I hope well get an answer...

Comment: @luckyging3r what are the odds for that double post / exact problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this doesn't work:

`File ->Project Structure -> App-> dependencies -> + ->add library`

In your `myProj` build.gradle file add:

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('../myLib/libs/somelib.jar')
}
```

`sync project with gradle files` and then `make project`

Comment: `implementation files('../myLib/libs/somelib.jar')` did the magic... Thanks!