# How to include internal jar files in android library

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, gson

I am trying to download and run an existing android studio project and currently I am getting the error:

`error: package com.google.gson does not exist`

The java file that needs gson is in the main app section. The `gson-2.8.1.jar` file is in a `client` library inside of a `libs` folder.

So the file structure looks a little like:

```
project_root
 |-- app/
 |   |-- src/
 |       |-- main/
 |           |-- java/
 |               |-- com.company.stuff/
 |                   |-- controller
 |                       |-- fileThatUsesGson.java
 |-- client/
     |-- libs/
         |-- gson-2.8.1.jar
```

The app `build.gradle` shows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(path: ':client')
}
```

The client `build.gradle` shows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/gson-2.8.1.jar')
}
```

This does seem to be an older project. I had to change `compile` to `implementation` which seems like it might be part of the problem but I can't seem to figure out how to add those `.jar` files.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is essentially what solved my problem stackoverflow.com/a/54818270/5184092

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Expanding on Mr.AF's answer:**

In the app `build.gradle` file I added

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('../client/libs/gson-2.8.1.jar')
}
```

`sync project with gradle files` and `make project`

**Original**

```
File ->Project Structure ->App-> dependencies -> + ->add library
```

Comment: I did that and fixed a couple other error. It gives me `Error: Program type already present: com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy` when I try to make the project. Is this because Gson already exists in the app now so when I load the `gson.jar` in the library it throws errors?

Comment: @luckyging3r if in your project .jar libs are being duplicated .try to reference in both gradle file to one existing .jar .

Comment: So that seemed to work. I had to manually type it. It seems like a "hack" to add `implementation files('../client/libs/gson-2.8.1.jar')`. Is that an appropriate way to add that file?

Comment: yea .i did it before .no problem they are in same scope and can use common rss.

Comment: I'll look into that more. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @luckyging3r if you faced any problem post here .i will help you.

Comment: @luckyging3r 1+